# Will users consider an invitation to a seminar a commercial solicitation?

Tags: email, perception, spam

From an email marketing perspective, could an invitation to a seminar be seen as a commercial solicitation?  In respect to the [CAN-SPAM Act](http://business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business), I would't think that a seminar is a product or a service, but more of a relational type of engagement.

On a side, not sure which SE site this question would best fit.  The rational I am taking in count is that I am trying to think about the user's perspective (the people that may potentially receive the invitation).

Comment: Are you asking purely from a UX point-of-view (do users appreciate being sent these type of emails if they've not requested to receive them) or are you more concerned with the legal aspect?

Comment: Well, a poor UX would/could lead to the legal aspect.  But for the intent of the question, I am just interested in the UX point-of-view.  I just through in the CAN-SPAM Act as the motive for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this depends on how you got the recipient's email addresses. If they have done business with you in the past that's related to the seminar I don't think it would be poorly received. I also think it would depend a bit on the intentions of the seminar (Willy Millions Get Rich Quick Expo at the Airport Holiday Inn vs. UX Techniques for Small Business Websites).

Comment: Good point on the "Get Rich Quick Expo".